# validate form inputs and enable button

Tags: javascript

What I need is to validate the form from the second section of the tab.

If there is any empty field of the 4 that does not appear hidden or transparent, the button should be disabled.

If they already have the 4 data, then the button is enabled.

The problem is that I add the two elements and for a reason the button is enabled since the last input has no data. And if I add a 3rd serious element, 6 fields to fill in or modify, because the data entry operator can proceed to delete an amount and the button should still be disabled even though the other 5 are filled with data
the inputs are `shoppingCartItemQuantity_` and `price_`.

How to make it take the inputs below the save button

Summary:

1. Leave button visible when all inputs are filled with data
2. Place focus on the input to fill the first one that is empty

```js
const id_prod = document.querySelector('#first-tab >#articulos>#productos_content>.tr >.id_n').textContent;
console.log(id_prod)

const tbody = document.querySelector('#second-tab >.shoppingCartItemsContainer > #form2 >#tabla >.tbody')
function updateCantidadNuevo(input) {
  if(input.checkValidity()){
   input.setAttribute("data-oldvalue", input.value);
  }
  else{
    input.value = input.getAttribute("data-oldvalue") || input.min;
  }
}
function add(id, cantidad=1){
  let input = document.querySelector('#shoppingCartItemQuantity_'+id);
  input.value= input.valueAsNumber + cantidad;
  updateCantidadNuevo(input);
  
console.log(id,input);
}



const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .button')
console.log(addToShoppingCartButtons)
addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach((addToCartButton) => {
  addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
  
  
  
  
  
  function addToCartClicked(event) {
  const button = event.target;
  
  const item = button.closest('.tr');

  const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent
  const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
  const talla = item.querySelector('.talla').textContent;

  
  addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod,  cantidad_disponible, talla);
}
function addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod,cantidad_disponible,talla) {
    

  if(cantidad_disponible!=0){
  const elementsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('title');

  for (let i = 0; i < elementsTitle.length; i++) {
    if (elementsTitle[i].innerText === id_prod) {
     
      return;
    }
  }

  const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.classList.add('ItemCarrito')
     tr.setAttribute("id", `tr_${id_prod}`);

  Content = `
     <th scope="row">${id_prod}</th>

     <td class="table__productos">
     <input id="id_productos_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${id_prod}" class="id_productos"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">

       <h6 id="title_${id_prod}" class="title" hidden>${id_prod}</h6>
     </td>

    
     <td class="table__cantidad_disponible">
     <input id="cantidad_disponible_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${cantidad_disponible}" class="cantidad_disponible"
     style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__talla">
    <input id="talla_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${talla}" class="talla"
   style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
     </td>

   



    
    
    <td class="table__cantidad">
                <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" max="${cantidad_disponible}" oninput="updateCantidad(this)" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" type="number" onblur="habilitar()"
                    value="1" min="1">
                
                </td>
         <td class="table__precio">
     <input required id="precio_${id_prod}" type="text" class="precio"   onchange="CarritoTotalmio()" min="0"onblur="habilitar()">
      
     </td>

     <td class="table__delete">
     <button class="delete btn btn-danger">x</button>
      
    </td>
     `
   
    
   tr.innerHTML = Content 
     tbody.append(tr)
}else{
  console.log("tiene un 0 imposible agregar");
}
}


});

function habilitar() {
  let nombreApellido = document.getElementById("shoppingCartItemQuantity_"+id_prod);
  let email = document.getElementById("precio_"+id_prod);
 
  let enviarBoton = document.getElementById("guardardatos");

  if (nombreApellido.value === '' || email.value === '') {
    enviarBoton.disabled = true;
  } else {
    enviarBoton.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
input[type=number] { -moz-appearance:textfield; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled-2</title>
  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
   
</head>
<body>



  

<section class="section">
      <div class="tabs">
         <ul class="tabs-menu">
          <li class="is-active" data-target="first-tab"><a>Tab one</a></li>
          <li data-target="second-tab"><a>Tab two</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="first-tab">

      <table id="articulos"class="table">
        <thead>
           
            <tr>
            
            <TH>id </TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>Añadir</TH>
              <TH>Añadir</TH>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="productos_content">
             <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">15<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 3</td>
            <td class="talla"> 36</td>
              
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(15)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
  
        </tr> 
       
       <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">1<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 7</td>
            <td class="talla"> 40</td>
          
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(1)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
    
        </tr> 
        </tbody>
        </table>
    
          </div>



      <div class="tab-content" id="second-tab">
      <div class="shopping-cart-items shoppingCartItemsContainer">
      <form id="form2" action="javascript:habilitar()">

<input type="button" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar" onchange="habilitar()" disabled />
   

      <table id="tabla" class="table">
 
            <tr>
            <TH>id</TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>   
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>          
            <TH>Añadir </TH>    
            </tr>
               <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
               
        </tbody>
    </table>

      <div class="float-right">
      Total:<input type="text" id="resultado_total" value="0" disabled > </input>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

<script>
    const tabSystem = {
    init(){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-menu').forEach(tabMenu => {
            Array.from(tabMenu.children).forEach((child, ind) => {
                child.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                });
                if(child.className.includes('is-active')){
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    toggle(targetId){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content').forEach(contentElement=>{
            contentElement.style.display = contentElement.id === targetId ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.querySelector(`[data-target="${contentElement.id}"]`).classList[contentElement.id === targetId ? 'add' : 'remove']('is-active');
        })
    },
};
// use it
tabSystem.init()
</script>


</html>
```

This is an example of how it should work.

My code to modify is the one above, that's the one that doesn't work

```js
const form = [...document.querySelectorAll('.form__element-input')];
const boton = document.querySelector('#enviar');

form.forEach((input, index) => {
    boton.classList.add('none__send');
    input.addEventListener('input', () => {
        if (form.some(el => el.value.trim() === "")) {
            boton.classList.add('none__send');
        } else {
            boton.classList.remove('none__send');
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.none__send {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="form">
    <div class="form__title">
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="number" name="cedula" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="number" name="telefono" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__button">
        <button type="submit" id="enviar">enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```